# Does sqlite3 support a trigger to automatically update an 'updated_on' datetime field?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this

```
user_id   |  name   |  created_on   |   updated_on
--------------------------------------------------
1         | Peter D | 1/1/2009      |
```

If I insert or update a record, I'd like a trigger to update the updated_on field with datetime('now'). But I can't find the function name to target the most recently updated row in sqlite3. Is there one?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: Thanks Hassan, The issue is that I can't find a way, from within a trigger, to target the last updated row in sqlite3. I use 'last_insert_rowid()' in another trigger. But I'm looking for 'last_update_rowid()' and can't find anything something like it.

Comment: The answer provided by @DougCurrie works really good! It is a pitty that the SQLite documentation is not so clear [Create trigger SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_table_trig AFTER UPDATE ON your_table
 BEGIN
  update your_table SET updated_on = datetime('now') WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
 END;
```

Comment: If this answered your question it is customary on SO to "Accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: if I'm not wrong then it throws an error like - An error occurred while committing the data: too many levels of trigger recursion

Comment: You may need to set `sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_TRIGGER_DEPTH,...)` -- see  https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6578439/1481479) for methods to avoid the trigger recursion issue without limiting trigger depth.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a trigger to update the `updated_on` column of your row when the row changes, however, the change invokes the same trigger again and you'll end up with the error `too many levels of trigger recursion`.
In order to avoid that, you can specify which columns you want the trigger to fire upon and of course you need to exclude `updated_on`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_table_trig 
AFTER UPDATE OF ID, 
  user_id, 
  name, 
  created_on ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE your_table 
SET updated_on = DATETIME ('NOW') 
WHERE rowid = new.rowid ; END;
```

Comment: This avoids the recursion problem, but introduces another one: you must remember to update the trigger every time you alter the schema. A nice workaround however when you know the schema won't change.