# update sqlite column with current date time in android

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I have a SQLite table in my android app which has a "MODIFIED" column. It basically stores when (date and time) the current row was first inserted or updated.

If i use `update()` function of SQLite DB in android, I can't figure out how to put a datetime value in the `ContentValues` parameter.

If I use `execSql()` method, i can use the `DATETIME()` sql function to get the current time is set it to the "MODIFIED" column. But this function does not have a return value. I wouldn't know if the update was successful or not.

Anyone who has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to create a 'TRIGGER' that updates MODIFIED automatically on each 'UPDATE' with SQLite itself, [read about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578439/on-update-current-timestamp-with-sqlite)

Comment: this is what i'm trying right now. This seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You just must do something like:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("modified", currentTime);
db.update("table", values, "_id = XXX", null);
```

Replace `_id = XXX` with the condition you want to use to update the rows. Update method returns the number of updated rows.

Also, you can use an integer instead of DATETIME (since they actually does not exist in sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) type for that column and pass `System.currentTimeMillis()` as `currentTime`.

Comment: The initial value of "MODIFIED" is of this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` so if I update to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, it will have a different format and my order by clause won't work.

Comment: Then just use that format, what's the problem? Take a look at the `SimpleDateFormat` class ;)