# Do sqlite triggers trigger other triggers?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, timestamp, sql-update

I am trying to implement the equivalent of the "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" MySQL feature in sqlite.
My idea it to use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE mytable SET last_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = old.id;
END
```

But there's a problem with this. Each time an update occurs on a record of this table, the trigger triggers a new update on this same record. This should trigger the trigger again, and again, leading to an infinite loop of updates.

Is this really what will happen? Will the update in my trigger trigger the trigger again?
Can I avoid triggering of triggers within triggers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're talking about SQLite, right?

Originally, recursive triggers (the infinite loop suspected above) were *not* supported specifically to prevent this problem.  They're now supported, but turned off by default.  You can, [in theory](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers), turn them back on with

```sql
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;
```

Answer (score 2):

For UPDATE triggers, you can specify on which columns it should trigger.
Just leave the `last_update` column out of that list:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_last_update
AFTER UPDATE OF col1, col2, etc ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET last_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE id = OLD.id;
END;
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I'd like to be able to add columns to the table and that the trigger still work for updates of the new columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `before update` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE
ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set new.last_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END;
```

Or, better yet, do this with a default value.

EDIT:

In SQLite, you could do this with an `instead of` trigger rather than a before trigger.  Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_update_trigger
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    update mytable
        set last_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            col1 = new.col1,
            col2 = new.col2,
            . . .
END;
```

However, I think the better choice would be a `default` clause in the table definition.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is syntactically correct. According to the doc at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html I need to have an UPDATE statement between the BEGIN and END. That should lead to the same problem I describe in the original post: an infinite loop. The actual original update that triggered the loop would never occur.

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL and this is allowable syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) for MySQL.  The SQLite syntax might be somewhat different.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to emulate a MySQL feature with sqlite. I don't need a MySQL solution since MySQL already does this with a simple `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` statement. I'm going to delete the mysql tag since it's confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff INSTEAD OF triggers are not allowed on tables.

Comment: @CL. . . . Somehow SQLite makes this much harder than it should be.  You could create a view and do the updates to the view.  I'm hoping someone else comes along with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

John, use the WHEN clause, it's work even with recursive triggers on.

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers=1;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS "mytable_last_update"
    AFTER UPDATE ON main.mytable FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN NEW.last_update < OLD.last_update
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable SET last_update=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE oid=OLD.oid;
END;
```

I'm using (strftime('%s','now')||substr(strftime('%f','now'),4)) instead CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, for using on web pages with Javascript Date() method.