# SQLite - SQL logic error or missing database near "ON": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

The following SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dsgdsgdsg` (`combo` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`combo`))
```

Returns:
`SQL logic error or missing database near "ON": syntax error`

Which seems to be related to "ON UPDATE", why is that? Is On Update not supported by SQLite? if so, is there an alternative (So that when I update using REPLACE INTO, I wont need to supply a new timestamp it just updates).

Comment: I've removed database tags you apparently don't use. Please refrain from tagging products not involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okey for a MySQL. However it's different in SQLite, use a trigger instead.
Someone had the same problem and was solved here [on update current_timestamp with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578439/on-update-current-timestamp-with-sqlite)